# How to present a secure, HTTP-only cookie as a bearer token (without Angular.JS)?

Tags: javascript, cookies, jwt, bearer-token

Is it possible to store a JWT as a secure, HTTP-only cookie **and** present it as a bearer token **without** using Angular.JS?

I assume that this might be possible, since Angular.JS has similar functionality (but I am not certain whether or not they utilize an HTTP-only cookie to store the token in).

Answer (score -2):

Hahahah yes...angularjs is just javascript

You need to find out what library is parsing the cookie on the back end..if you're using express, for example, you're probably using cookieParser...you can just console.log(req.cookie), and you can see all the cookies that are sent.

You can set a cookie pretty simply like this document.cookie="jwt=asdlfasdf".

If you are setting the cookie on the server though, which you probably are, your browser will automatically set that when it receives the `Set-Cookie` header...you can read more about the `Set-Cookie` header here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie

Comment: Zane, Thanks, but that does not even come close to answering the question. The answer to the question should not involve setting the cookie, which is assumed to be done. The question is whether or not a JWT that is stored in a secure, HTTP-only cookie can be presented as a bearer token (bearer authorization header) and, if so, how? (I am starting to suspect that this might not be possible to do, but if it could be done, it would be extremely convenient.)